# Phundament under Windows - "Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows"

Tags: windows, docker-compose, phundament

I have Docker Toolbox installed under Windows 7. The Docker daemon is running inside a VM (the default behavior of Docker Toolbox).

I am trying to get Phundament running using the [default tutorial](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/master/README.md).

It all works fine until I reach this command:
`docker-compose run php composer install`

It results in:

[image]

I've successfully attached to the running container using `docker exec -it <container ID> bash` but when I do a `ls /app` command on any of the two containers I get no files in that directory. In effect, the attempt to run `composer install` there fails.

I tried attaching to both containers and the result is identical.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that behavior just recently, it's sadly a limitation of `docker-compose` on Windows.

For the command you mentioned you can actually run

```
docker-compose run -d php composer install
```

As general workarounds...

- use `docker exec -it app_php_1 bash`

  - see also https://getcarina.com/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-cannot-enable-tty-mode-on-windows/
- if you don't really need an interactive shell, you could just run a command or script, like `docker-compose run -d php setup.sh`

*Note: I need to double-check the above suggestions on a real Windows testing system.*

PS: I am the author if Phundament. I've also just created an [issue for this](https://github.com/phundament/app/issues/200).

Comment: Unfortunately, the detached option doesn't work. I get a new container and it dies immediately. Checking it's log I see an error along the lines of `composer.json not found in folder`. Apparently the /app folder is blank for some reason (trying `ls /app`).

Comment: It looks like there is some hope for a (relatively) straightforward resolution here. There is a definite workaround, where you can `docker-compose up` a container, then `docker exec -it <something interactive>`... I'm not sure if it's just not possible to use the Python pty stuff on Windows, but using Cmder, other tty things work pretty well. It may be that these checks just need to test for tty rather than "am I on Windows?"   https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/cli/main.py#L534

Comment: @hasMobi If you're missing `composer.json` it's very likely that there's something wrong with host-volumes if you're running in local development mode or volumes/volumes_from in testing/staging - depending on your setup. Could you double-check this, eg. with `docker inspect`

This is the issue from docker/compose btw: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2836

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
winpty docker-compose run php composer install
```

it works for example:

```
winpty docker run --rm -it debian bash
```

Comment: Using `winpty` didn't help. I got the same error when not using it.